# TableView in OSX with Swift

Tags: macos, swift, tableview, osx-yosemite

I am new in swift and I'm trying to make an example of creating tables, I followed the following tutorial

[Swift NSTableView sample code](http://www.knowstack.com/swift-nstableview-sample-code/)

but I have many errors.If someone can help me because I do not understand because they come.

[image: errors]

[image]

and only print

[image: table without text]

Comment: Please post the full compile error.

Comment: I And remove the error by using the AutoLayout , but do not print anything arrangement within the table , someone could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linkage libraries dependency in **Embedded Binaries** can cause that problem, try to remove all of it from your **General** settings. Try to build again.

[image]